# Convert Quaternion to Matrix4x4

Tags: unity, rotation, matrix, quaternion

I'm trying to set `Gizmos.matrix` which is a 4x4 by matrix such that the gizmos drawn match the rotation of the object. However, I'm not sure how to convert the `transform.rotation` quaternion to a `Matrix4x4`. The Unity documentation points to a function called `Matrix4x4.Rotate()`, but Unity 5.6 does not seem to recognize any such function under `Matrix4x4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Matrix4x4.TRS function.
It takes a position vector, rotation quat, and a scale vector and outputs a Matrix 4x4.

```
public static Matrix4x4 TRS(Vector3 pos, Quaternion q, Vector3 s);
```

to draw the gizmo in the scene, use

```
//Just as one color assignment applies to every gizmo, 
//You must be sure to assign the correct matrix
Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position,transform.rotation,transform.localScale);
Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero,Vector3.one);
```

Or alternatively:

```
Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;
```

Link to unity docs: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.TRS.html

Comment: How do I use it such that the position and scale remain unchanged?

Comment: I guess I can set `s` to `Vector3.one`, but what about `pos`?

Comment: I've revised my answer to include a use case.